# Copy photos from memory card (How do I manually start the wizard?)

Tags: windows, photos, memory-card

I want to copy photos from my camera's memory card using Windows photo copy wizard, however I'm not connecting the camera directly (I lost the cable) rather I'm inserting the camera's SD memory card into the memory card's slot. Windows (Vista) recognizes the memory card and I can explore the photos but it doesn't automatically launch the "Device connected, what do you want to do" wizard. How do I manually launch the photo copy wizard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you would have an option called `AutoPlay` when you do right-clicking on the memory card. Ths will launch the autoply dialog, that usually comes popping.

Sometimes, autplay may *vanish*. See [this link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/01/14/autoplayautorun-not-working-or-missing-not-open-in-windows-vista/) for more details on how to get it back.

Comment: Nope, no such option :o(

Comment: Oh! :(  Thats seriously a problem. Check my edited answer. that link might help you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't answering your question as stated, but the simplest way to get the photos off the memory card is to open Windows Explorer and browse to the memory card "disk". There'll be a folder called DCIM (or something similar), keep expanding this until you find a folder containing `jpg` files and just copy them to your PC's hard drive as  you would any other file.

Obviously this won't allow you to perform actions on each file such as renaming, setting EXIF (property) data etc.

Comment: This doesn't provide the renaming option which is why I want the wizard in the first place.

Comment: @Motti - OK, but you didn't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using XP professional, and if you go to My Computer, and right click on the drive you want, select Properties and click on Auto Play, select the type of file you have (ie photos, video etc.) and then select an action it should show as "copy pictures etc." and if you select that, then "apply" at the bottom, it should show up the next time you plug it in. Hope this helps.

Comment: This adds nothing to the accepted answer.